# Error CS0616 from the post processing unity stack

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, post-processing

I can't seem to find why the unity post-processing stack give me the CS0616 error on every scripts.. A lot of people seem to love and use it, but when i import it, it tells me that "`UnityEditor.PostProcessing.PostProcessingModelEditor': is not an attribute class" and googling it doesn't put me on track.. neither do msft related page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0616

Does anyone have an idea about what obvious thing I must be missing?
[image]

Comment: You need to show the code that is causing the error.  The error description seems pretty clear.

Comment: Can you share the code of PostProcessingModelEditor ?

Comment: What's your Unity version ?